# Android collapse EditText in ActionBar(Sherlock) after search is pressed on keyboard

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-edittext

I was having some weird (keyboard related) issue in my app caused by the way I was programmatically collapsing an `EditText` inside an `ActionBarSherlock`.

This is what I was doing:

```
if(searchMenuItem!=null){
    searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
}
```

Does anyone know if there is any other way of collapsing the ActionBar?

**Edit:**

I've noticed that the same problem happens when I click on the application icon on the top left corner of the screen. Is `collapseActionView` called implicitly here? How can I know if this issue is caused by some unknown part of my code?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
if(searchMenuItem!=null && searchMenuItem.getActionView() != null){
     searchMenuItem.setActionView(null);
}
```

(Of course you'd need to set it again when the relevant menu item is pressed).

Comment: Tried it now, buy unfortunately it didn't work, the actionbar didn't collapse

Comment: Sorry, you need to collapse the whole actionBar? In that case, you can just do getSupportActionBar().hide()

Comment: No, I think that I was not clear in formulating my question. I want the MenuItem to collapse. when i use collapseActionView(); weird things happen to the keyboard (it shows return instead of the magnifying glass)